# files created by PHP deleted on exit

Tags: php, file, fopen, exit, fwrite

I am writing some files in the filesystem, but unfortunately these files are deleted at the exit of the PHP script.

I have tried to create the files both with fopen (w+) and file_put_contents. Files are regularly deleted.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Files are written to /home/ontw/webshop/definitions1/, which is not a temporary directory.

some code:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "w+");

if ($fp == false) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Could not create $filename (fopen error)!");
}

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
  if (false === fwrite($fp, $contents)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not create $filename (fwrite error)!");
  }

  fflush($fp);
  flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
} else {
  throw new RuntimeException("Could not create $filename (unable to get file lock)!");
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Add more details in your question

Comment: Where are you writing them to? If you're writing into `/tmp`, I guess that's expected behaviour. Can you show some code?

Comment: It might be overwritted and not deleted.

Comment: @Pekka웃 : the directory is not temporary

Comment: @vinoth-babu : what do you mean?

Comment: Does the behaviour change if you write something to the file?

Comment: no, the file is correctly written and gets deleted on exit

Comment: How do you know it gets deleted on exit? Is the file missing immediately after the script completes or later at a periodic time. If it is gone immediately after the script, how do you know it is written correctly in the first place?

Comment: What type of environment are you using? Is this your own server or a shared hosting platform? Have you asked the hosting provider about it?

Comment: I found the bug! The deletion of the file was performed inside of a __destruct !!!! This is why it was so difficult to debug! Thanks to everybody for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug.
The deletion was performed inside a `__destruct` statement. It seems that all the destructors are called on `exit()`